# viewDidLayoutSubviews is getting called infinitely after switching to xcode 6

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode6.3

My perfectly working iOS app stopped working properly after switching to xcode 6. I found out that in one of my view controllers viewDidLayoutSubviews method is getting called infinitely until the memory level reaches to some point when the app is crashing due to that.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening? I also noticed that some of my views started to look weird after switching to xcode 6, but I fixed those issues in storyboard.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

EDIT 1.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if (self.showsPlayerControls == NO) {
        self.playerControlsView.hidden = YES;
        CGRect graphFrame = self.view.bounds;

        graphFrame.size.height = graphFrame.size.height - 20.0f;
        graphFrame.origin.y = 20.0f;

        self.graphView.frame = graphFrame;   
    }

    [self.graphView reloadData];
}
```

EDIT 2.

My fix is the following, basically move my code to viewWillAppear.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.showsPlayerControls == NO) {
        self.playerControlsView.hidden = YES;
        CGRect graphFrame = self.view.bounds;

        graphFrame.size.height = graphFrame.size.height - 20.0f;
        graphFrame.origin.y = 20.0f;

        self.graphView.frame = graphFrame;
    }

    [self.graphView reloadData];
}
```

Is this a good equivalent of what I want to achieve ?

Comment: Can you post your `viewDidLayoutSubviews` implementation please?

Comment: As Tommy says in the comment below, this is because you're adjusting the bounds of the `graphView`, which is causing `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to be called again, thus creating an infinite loop. Moving the code to `viewWillAppear` seems like a suitable solution.

Comment: Helped a ton, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.showsPlayerControls == NO) {
        self.playerControlsView.hidden = YES;
        CGRect graphFrame = self.view.bounds;

        graphFrame.size.height = graphFrame.size.height - 20.0f;
        graphFrame.origin.y = 20.0f;

        self.graphView.frame = graphFrame;
    }

    [self.graphView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the frame of the subview is triggering a fresh layout. `NSLayoutConstraint`s mean that there's no longer a fixed hierarchy to how the need to layout propagates.

Quick fix:

```
if (!CGRectEqualToRect(self.graphView.frame, graphFrame))
    self.graphView.frame = graphFrame;
```

If `reloadData` adds or subtracts subviews it will have the same effect. If you're reloading data only because of a frame change, do that when setting the frame only. If you're using `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to infer something other than merely that subviews were laid out then stop.

Comment: this one doesn't fix the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I set the headerView of UITableview as the current updated headerView, viewDidLayoutStubviews gets called infinitely. So I forced it so that setting the headerView only happens once with an Bool variable.

```
var headerViewSet = false
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        commentsForRejected.numberOfLines = 0
        commentsForRejected.text = "ABCDSAFMLDSFMWL W MELWFKMLWKFMLAWEKFM AWFMALWEFKMWELKFMLAWKF ANFOAWEFNAJWEFKNAEW AFNWKEFNKAWJFNEW"
        self.headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: headerView.frame.size.width, height: headerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height)
        if headerViewSet == false {
            tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView
            headerViewSet = true
        }
    }
```